# How to put a loop on an sapply function to create a subset for multiple participants?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, sapply

I would appreciate some help on the following problem:

I have mutiple huge Logfiles (>1.000.000 entries each) which contain some lines (rows) that are of particular interest for me. So I want to make a subset containing just these lines, but I want to write the result in matrix containing the information for more then one Logfile/Participant. So I created a short line of code to 1. create the subset and 2. run it within a loop, to do it not only for one of the Logfiles, but for all of them.

```
  Result <- subset(df, df$columnOfInterest== "interestingCondition1" | df$columnOfInterest== "interestingCondition2" | df$columnOfInterest== "interestingCondition3")$columnOfInterest
  View(Result)

1
interestingCondition1
2
interestingCondition1
3
interestingCondition2
4
interestingCondition1
5
interestingCondition1
6
interestingCondition3
7
interestingCondition2
8
interestingCondition1
9
interestingCondition1
10
interestingCondition1
```

Embeded into a loop:

```
WrongResult <- matrix(data=NA,nrow=TrialNumber, ncol=length(ListOfFiles))
vpncount <- 1
for (v in ListOfFiles){

  df<- read.delim(v, header = TRUE, sep='\t')
  WrongResult[,vpncount] <- subset(df, df$columnOfInterest== "interestingCondition1" | df$columnOfInterest== "interestingCondition2" | df$columnOfInterest== "interestingCondition3")$columnOfInterest

vpncount <- vpncount+1

}
```

When running the code on one Logfile I get the result I would like, but when running it through the loop, it creates a matrix with the appropiate size, but just filled with "random" numbers instead of the conditions I subdivded for.

Does anyone knows why that happens and how to fix it? Any help is appreciated a lot!

EDIT:

I tried to create an example data frame. The first line of code (including the variable Results) works just as I want it to be. It filters my dataframe on the rows of my columnOfInterest and puts them into a new matrix. But if I try to run it within a loop for more then one dataframe I keep running into errors:

```
df <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  columnOfInterest= sample(c("interestingCondition1", "interestingCondition2", "interestingCondition3", "NotinterestingCondition1"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

View(df)

Result <- subset(df, df$columnOfInterest== "interestingCondition1" | df$columnOfInterest== "interestingCondition2" | df$columnOfInterest== "interestingCondition3")$columnOfInterest
View(Result)

WrongResult <- matrix(data=NA,nrow=280, ncol=20)
vpncount <- 1
for (v in 1:20){

  df<- read.delim(v, header = TRUE, sep='\t')
  WrongResult[,vpncount] <- subset(df, df$columnOfInterest== "interestingCondition1" | df$columnOfInterest== "interestingCondition2" | df$columnOfInterest== "interestingCondition3")$columnOfInterest

  vpncount <- vpncount+1

}

View(WrongResult)
```

Comment: I don't see your sapply function?

Comment: Yes, you are rught, I am really sorry. I tested a couple of solution and above I replaced the sapply line with the subset() one. Here is the other idea, which worked as well for me, but the problem of putting it into a loop (therefore running it over multiple dataframes) still exists.

Comment: WrongResult2 <- t(sapply(seq(length = nrow(df)), function(x) df[x, "columnOfIntertest"] %in% c("interstingCondition1", "interstingCondition2", "interstingCondition3")))
View(WrongResult2 )

Comment: Please correct the typos in your sample data -- `columnOfInterest`, `interestingCondition1`

Comment: @MartinMorgan Done, sorry for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone knows why that happens?

Your loop is… not working. The reasons are a bit complex, but I've made a working example in base R using simple loops (no *apply functions), hopefully you can follow along, and hopefully it represents your problem to a sufficient degree.

Learn to walk before you run. Learn basic loops before you learn how to do it more succinctly with `apply()`, `lapply()` etc. Learn standard evaluation (i.e. regular use of  the programming language R itself) before you delve into non-standard evaluation (`data.table`, `tidyverse`, `purrr` etc.)

First we'll create some data frames and write them to files

```
owd <- getwd()
dir.create("sotest")
setwd("sotest")

set.seed(1)

flist <- c("dtf1.txt", "dtf2.txt", "dtf3.txt")

for (i in 1:length(flist)) {
    dtf <- data.frame(
      X=sample(1:10),
      coi=sample(c("ic1", "ic2", "ic3", "nic1"), 10, replace=TRUE)
    )
    write.table(dtf, flist[i], row.names=FALSE, sep="\t")
}
```

After running this you should have a folder named "sotest" containing three tab-separated txt-files.

Then we'll get a list of available files, and loop over that.

```
flist <- list.files(pattern=".txt")
WrongResult <- list()
interesting <- c("ic1", "ic2", "ic3")

for (v in 1:length(flist)) {

    dtf <- read.delim(flist[v], header=TRUE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    WrongResult[[v]] <- dtf[dtf$coi %in% interesting, "coi"]

}

WrongResult

setwd(owd)
```

I store the output is a list instead of a matrix, as the length of the object produced in each iteration of the loop isn't the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution worked really nice for me and I appreciate it alot that you took some extra time and effort to explain it to beginners and with an approach not involving a lot of new packages. I could follow it just fine and use it for my problem. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how to do it with data.frame so I'll try with data.table. You might have to install the data.table package in case you don't have it `install.packages("data.table")`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
```

Then you could rewrite your code in the following way

```
subset..table <- function(dt){
    dt[columnOfInterest %in% c("interestingCondition1",
                               "interestingCondition2",
                               "interestingCondition3"),columnOfInterest]
}


myfun <- function(x){
### DD
    ## x interp string representing  file name

### Purpose
    ## read and subset

    dt <- fread(x,header=TRUE,sep="\t")
    subset..table(dt)

}

res..list <- lapply(ListOfFiles, myfun)
```

**Edit**

for instance using your example.

```
df <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  columnOfInterest= sample(c("interestingCondition1",
    "interestingCondition2", "interestingCondition3", 
    "NotinterestingCondition1"), 10, replace = TRUE))


dt <- data.table(df)
subset..table(dt)
```

would yield

```
#[1] "interestingCondition2" "interestingCondition3" "interestingCondition1"
#[4] "interestingCondition2" "interestingCondition1" "interestingCondition2"
#[7] "interestingCondition3" "interestingCondition1" "interestingCondition3"
```

If you are satisfied with the function subset..table, then you just need to use the function myfun to get what you want. The function `fread` will automatically give you a `data.table`.

Comment: I only see `fread()` as dependent on `data.table`. Can't you replace that with `read.delim()` as used by the OP?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. The error message tells us, that columnOfInterest (object) was not found. Any idea, why that is?

Comment: How? I see nothing that is specific to `data.table` there.

Comment: @AlexB.: If you give us a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it will be easier to give you a working solution.

Comment: @DJJ columnOfInterest is one column of `code` df `code`. @AkselA I am working on a reproducible example, since my dataframe is to big to be copied directly.

Comment: you don't have to put the entire table just the smallest sample would be enough. read the reproducible example link. It might give you some hint.

Comment: @DJJ: I have edited the question and added an example that hopefully illustrated the problem a bit better.

Comment: @DJJ Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it! It worked just fine for one dataframe and probably for more as well, but I haven´t tested it, bacause I took AkselA´s solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the tidyverse realm when you're processing a single data frame you'd like to `filter()` and then `select()` your original data, and for convenience add, using `mutate()`, the file name. A nice way to filter when there are several possible values is using `%in%`. So

```
library(tidyverse)

process_1_df <- function(df, id, condition)
    select(df, columnOfInterest) %>%                 # only interesting column
        filter(columnOfInterest %in% condition) %>%  # specific rows
        mutate(id = id)                              # add identifier

condition <- paste0("interestingCondition", 1:3)
process_1_df(df, "id", condition)
```

`id` is meant to be an identifier -- if the data.frame came from file 'foo.txt', then use `"foo.txt"` for the id. The original question tried to represent data from several files as a matrix, but that assumes that each file has the same number of interesting rows selected. Here the strategy is to create a data frame that contains the file that the interesting condition came from, and the value of the interesting condition. This data frame is useful when processing several files...

This works on the sample data set as:

```
> condition <- paste0("interestingCondition", 1:3)
> process_1_df(df, "id", condition)
       columnOfInterest id
1 interestingCondition2 id
2 interestingCondition2 id
3 interestingCondition3 id
4 interestingCondition1 id
5 interestingCondition3 id
6 interestingCondition1 id
```

You might extend this to process a file

```
process_1_file <- function(file_name, condition)
    read_csv(file_name) %>%                   # better: input only columnOfInterest
        process_1_df(file_name, condition)
```

As @DJJ suggests, a data.table implementation of `process_1_file()` is likely to be very compact and efficient -- `fread(file_name)[columnOfInterest %in% condition, columnOfInterest]`

To process several files, use the purr package

```
library(purrr)
process_files <- function(file_names, condition)
    map(file_names, process_1_file, condition) %>%
        bind_rows()

dir(pattern="*.csv") %>% process_files(condition)
```

The end result is a single data frame, with a column of interesting conditions and another column indicating which log file the interesting condition came from. This 'long'-format data frame can now be processed / summarized as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! I tried to use the code, but the result is not filtered for. The resulting matrix consistes of all 10 rows of the provided sample dataframe and the NotinterestingCondition1 is still included. I can´t really follow your code, since the mentioned packages and R in general is pretty new for me. Do you now why this happens?

Comment: did you ensure that the typos were corrected? I updated my post to demonstrate that it works.

Comment: Copying your updated code I still get the following error message: ' Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "condition" is missing, with no default.'

Comment: did you define the condition variable, `condition <- paste0("interestingCondition", 1:3)` indicating the condition(s) of interest?

Comment: Yes I did and it works proparly: `condition
[1] "interestingCondition1" "interestingCondition2" "interestingCondition3`. Still the function is not working: `process_1_df(df, condition)
 Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "condition" is missing, with no default.`

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my 'illustration' but not the original script; see the update

Comment: Nice, `process_1_df` works just as I would like it to work, thanks a lot. Only thing there I don´t understand is `id`. What is it used for and what should I edit there? But even more important is the usage for multiple data frames. My Logfiles are `.txt` and not csv. What part of your code do I have to edit then?

Comment: I tried to add explanation for id to the answer, and the rationale for creating a data frame for each log file. You'll need to modify the step `read_csv(file_name)` to perform whatever operation will get your data from the text file into R as a data frame; only you know the format of the text file, so I can't help you there...

Comment: Thank you very much. Modifying `read_csw(file_name)` probably would have worked just fine, but I haven´t tested it, bacuase AkselA´s solution worked fine for me as well.

Comment: not modify `read_csv()` but if AkselA's code works for your files then replace `read_csv(file_name)` with `read.delim(file_name, header = TRUE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` ; glad you found a solution anyway